AWS Lambda with Docker Image: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
I have a Dockerfile that uses a base image from a third party that uses FROM rockylinux:8 as its base image and the repo currently produces an image that is used in ECS. I am trying to make this container runnable on AWS lambda environment while also maintaining the ECS image functionality.
Reviewing the requirements (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-reqs), it looks like I need to install the Lambda runtime API for python in the image I am creating and then update the ENTRYPOINT. I used the example Dockerfile under "creating an image from an alternative base image" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-clients) as a reference and modified the Dockerfile. Below is a reduced version that anyone should be able to use:
FROM rockylinux:8.9
RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y upgrade
HEALTHCHECK NONE
RUN yum install -y nano && \
    yum install -y wget

RUN adduser worker
USER worker
ARG HOME='/home/worker'
WORKDIR $HOME
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py310_23.10.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh && \
    bash miniconda.sh -b -p ${HOME}/miniconda && \
    rm miniconda.sh && \
    source ${HOME}/miniconda/bin/activate && \
    conda init --all
ENV PATH="${HOME}/miniconda/bin:${PATH}"
ARG BUILD=${HOME}/build
RUN mkdir ${BUILD}

COPY lambda_function.py ${BUILD}
RUN pip install --target ${BUILD} awslambdaric

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/worker/miniconda/bin/python3.10", "-m", "awslambdaric"]
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]

But I'm getting the following error while testing on Lambda function
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: d8919b62-472d-46c9-acf3-2b5ddaf49264 Error: fork/exec /home/worker/miniconda3/bin/python3.10: permission denied"
}

When I run the container locally the permissions look as follows:
[worker@7525b61497ad bin]$ ls -al python3.10
-rwxrwxr-x 1 worker worker 17157264 Apr 10 19:14 python3.10

And I am able to run python:
[worker@7525b61497ad bin]$ python
Python 3.10.13 (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:44:35) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

Sample project structure:
test
├── Dockerfile
└── lambda_function.py

lambda_function.py contents:
import sys

def handler(event, context):
    return 'Hello from AWS Lambda using Python' + sys.version + '!'

Update: Removing the RUN adduser worker and USER worker resolves the issue but I do not know why at the moment.

Can you run import awslambdaric from the miniconda copy of Python?

@AnonCoward If I cd to the build directory first it will allow me to import.
